# Agrupamento de Array?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte `array`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cor
            [1] => Azul
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peso
            [1] => 100kg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Espessura
            [1] => 10cm
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cor
            [1] => Azul
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cor
            [1] => adg
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Peso
            [1] => gadg
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cor
            [1] => Preto
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Espessura
            [1] => 325
        )

)
```

e preciso que fique agrupado da seguinte forma:

```
Array
(
    [Cor] => Array
        (
            [0] => Azul 
            [1] => adg
            [2] => Preto
        )

    [Peso] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100kg
            [1] => gadg
        )

    [Espessura] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10cm
            [1] => 325
        )
)
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de se obter esse resultado em `php`?

Comment: Como é gerado esse *array*? Dependendo de como for, será melhor modificar a criação dele do que apenas adaptá-lo. Aliás, o que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Qual é a regra?

Comment: Bom dia Anderson, seria
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $descri = $row['descri_produto']; //ex. $descri = " - Cor: Azul - Espessura: 10cm";
  $teste = explode(' - ', $descri);
  foreach ($teste as $key => $value) {
   if ($teste != '') {
    $teste2 = explode(': ', $value,2);
    $arr_teste[] = $teste2;
   };
  };
 };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se vier sempre nessa estrutura isso aqui resolve:

```
$arr = [ 
    [''], 
    ['Cor', 'Azul'], 
    ['Peso', '100kg'],
    ['Espessura', '10cm'],
    [''],
    ['Cor', 'Azul'],
    [''],
    ['Cor', 'adg'],
    ['Peso', 'gadg'],
    [''],
    ['Cor', 'Preto'],
    ['Espessura', '325']
];

$n = [];
foreach($arr as $value) {
    if(isset($value[1])) {
        if(!in_array($value[1], $n[$value[0]])) {
            $n[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($n);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [Cor] => Array
        (
            [0] => Azul
            [1] => adg
            [2] => Preto
        )

    [Peso] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100kg
            [1] => gadg
        )

    [Espessura] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10cm
            [1] => 325
        )

)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @JuniorNunes, era exatamente isso que precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo reduzido:

```
<?php

    $ar = array(
            array(),
            array('cor', 'azul'),
            array('peso', '192kg'),
            array('espessura', '10cm'),
            array(),
            array('cor', 'azul'),
            array(),
            array('cor', 'adg'),
            array('peso', 'adg'),
            array(),            
            array('cor', 'preto'),          
            array('espessura', '325')
        );

    $ar1 = array();
    foreach($ar as $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 2)
        {
            $ar1[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
        }
    }

    var_dump($ar1);
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](https://repl.it/KSfy/2)